# Serilog does not recreate log file after file has been deleted

Tags: logging, serilog

I using Serilog and have little problem when I delete my log file while program running.
For example I have program with button which will write to log file error info on click.
First click button will create log file and write error. I delete log file now and click button again - log file is not create again so serilog can not write information. If I reload my program, Serilog will create log file on first click again and write some information into it. Below is method which I using to write into log file and serilog configuration which is load on the start program. Can I do something to force serilog to recreate log file?

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void Write(LogEventLevel logEvent, string message)
    {
        Log.Write(logEvent, message);
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }

    public static void ConfigureSerilog()
    {
        var logFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "OSync\\OSync.log");

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.File(logFile, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, fileSizeLimitBytes: 2097152, retainedFileCountLimit: 7)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
}
```

Comment: Serilog won't create a file until after an event is logged and written. It does not pre-emptively create files.

Comment: I do not understand. Serilog create for me log file.
Button -> Event -> Creating File -> Write to file
Next click will looks like that:  Button -> Event -> Write to file (because file exists)
I delete file now and should be again Button -> Event -> Creating File -> Write to file but file is not created ;/

Comment: You need to `Flush` Serilog too.

Comment: My main problem was log file lock by my app - when my app run, I can not delete log file, so I used `Log.CloseAndFlush` but file do not recreate after delete. I added my method `ConfigureSerilog()` on the end of my Write method, so my log file is create again if I delete it. I'm sure that's not the best solution, but works for me and I do not have other idea. Anyway, thanks! :)